# how to display looped objects in windows form

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach

am trying to show the result of a foreach loop in a textbox. if it was a console application i could easily do this 
Console.WriteLine("{0}" "{1}" "{2}", serial, state, capital);
but its a windows form application and i want to display the result in a textbox.

```
List<StatesCapital> stacap = new List<StatesCapital>();
            stacap.Add(new StatesCapital { sn = 1, st = "Anambra", ca = "Awka" });
            stacap.Add(new StatesCapital { sn = 2, st = "Abia", ca = "Umuahia" });
            stacap.Add(new StatesCapital { sn = 3, st = "Bauchi", ca = "Bauchi" });

            var std = from s in stacap select s;

            foreach (var stud in std)
           {
               //converting the looped to string
              string serial = Convert.ToString((stud.sn));
              string state = Convert.ToString(stud.st);
              string capital = Convert.ToString(stud.ca);

                //now to display the results in a textbox
                displaystates.Text = ("{0}" "{1}" "{2}", serial, state, capital);
        }
```

Comment: so what's wrong with this ?

Comment: You probably want to append instead of replacing the text.

Comment: Use a grid instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can **append** Text to your TextBox:

```
displaystates.Text += string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \n", serial, state, capital);
```

The `+=` operator for strings takes the left side, appends the right side and assign the new value to the left side.
`string.Format` is called from `Console.WriteLine` too and formats the passed format-string with its values.
Notice the `\n` at the end of the format-string. This adds a line break.

Another (often faster) way to output all lines is to use a `StringBuilder`.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

//in your loop: add the lines
sb.AppendFormat(("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \n", serial, state, capital);

//after your loop: output the result to the TextBox:
displaystates.Text = sb.ToString();
```

`StringBuilder.AppendFormat` do the same thing as `string.Format` but adds it result with a line break to the `StringBuilder`-instance which can be converted into a string by calling `ToString()`.

PS: If you use C# 6 you should look at adv12 answer too. The interpolated strings with $"" are often better readable than `string.Format` or `AppendFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in C# 6, try this instead:

```
displaystates.Text = $"{serial} {state} {capital}";
```

This takes advantage of a cool new string feature, interpolated strings.

To do it the "old way," try this:

```
displaystates.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", serial, state, capital);
```

**Edit**: I just noticed the part about doing this within a foreach loop, which means you probably want your `TextBox` to show results from every line, not just the most recent.  In that case, use `+=` as @Koopakiller suggests, and don't forget the `\r\n` at the end of the line.